# Can't use IF for create or alter view depending on view's existense

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to achieve what the code below suggests, but I'm getting the error `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'view'` on both the create and alter lines.

```
IF Object_ID('TestView') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        create view TestView
        as
        . . .
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        ALTER view TestView
        as
        . . .   
    END
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because ALTER/CREATE commands can't be within BEGIN/END blocks. You need to test for existence and the drop it before doing a create

```
IF Object_ID('TestView') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW TestView

GO

CREATE VIEW TestView
   as
   . . .

GO
```

If you are woried about the permissions being lost you can script the GRANT statements as well and re-run those at the end.

You could wrap the create/alter into a string and do an EXEC - that might get ugly for large views

```
DECLARE @SQL as varchar(4000)

-- set to body of view
SET @SQL = 'SELECT X, Y, Z FROM TABLE' 

IF Object_ID('TestView') IS NULL
    SET @SQL = 'CREATE VIEW TestView AS ' + @SQL
ELSE    
    SET @SQL = 'ALTER VIEW TestView AS ' + @SQL

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: Dropping the view, as opposed to altering it, loses the permission settings on the view.

Comment: IF you are woried about the permissions being lost you can script the GRANT statements as well and re-run those at the end.

Comment: This isn't correct.  I use Begin end blocks with create table statements all the time when introducing a new table design to a database.

Comment: don't need EXEC(@SQL) while create or alter

Answer (score 10):

I was going to comment on the answer from ProfK, but couldn't figure out how to format for code in a comment, so here it is an an answer.

---

Using sp_executesql is better, but don't you need to indicate it's an nvarchar?  Otherwise I get this error:  Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Here's what I use as a view template:

```
If not exists (Select Table_Name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS where Table_Name = 'vMessage') begin 
    exec sp_executesql N'create view vMessage as select test = 1'
    print 'Creating view vMessage'
end 

print 'Altering view vMessage'
go
Alter view vMessage 
as
Select 
* 
from Message
```

Comment: +1 This, unlike most of the suggestions, does not delete existing permissions to the view.

Answer (score 5):

An esteemed colleague helped me on this:

```
if object_id('demoView') is null
    sp_executesql 'create view demoView as select * from demoTable'
```

works just fine.

Comment: I found this to be very helpful! I just wanted to add that if you're doing this from within a begin/end block, you'll need to toss an 'EXEC' in front of the command.

Answer (score 5):

Working & easy solution:

Just wrap your sql with EXEC keyword. Note that you need only to give quotes once, even in multiline sql:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(select * FROM sys.views where name = 'TestView')
  BEGIN    
    EXEC ('
      CREATE VIEW [dbo].[TestView]
      AS
        SELECT
          *
        FROM
          dbo.SomeTable
    ')
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    EXEC ('
      ALTER VIEW [dbo].[TestView]
      AS
        SELECT
          *
        FROM
          dbo.SomeTable
    ')
  END
```

Answer (score 1):

You should drop the view if it's created then only do an alter

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TestView') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 

DROP VIEW TestView
END

GO

CREATE VIEW TestView

AS 

SELECT * FROM TestTable
```

Comment: the original question never said anything about keeping permissions. I'd assume the permissions would be in the script with the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it that avoids `sp_execute_sql`:

```
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT  1
                FROM    sysobjects
                WHERE   type = 'V'
                        AND name = 'vwTradeEventTemp' )
        BEGIN
            DROP VIEW [dbo].[vwTradeEventTemp];
        END;
    GO

    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vwTradeEventTemp]
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
    AS
    select col1, col2 from table
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  1
                FROM    sysobjects
                WHERE   type = 'V'
                        AND name = 'vwTradeEvent' )
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'vwTradeEvent does not exist, renaming vwTradeEventTemp to vwTradeEvent to work around not being able to check for view existence before creating';
            EXEC sp_rename @objname = 'vwTradeEventTemp',
                @newname = 'vwTradeEvent', @objtype = 'object';
        END;
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'vwTradeEvent already exists, dropping vwTradeEventTemp';
            DROP VIEW dbo.vwTradeEventTemp;
        END;
```

I don't like using sp_executesql as you lose the syntax highlighting and parsing also doesn't work... This is also handy as it avoids dropping the view. In my case, the view is used in replication so dropping it fails unless replication is dropped and recreated.

Answer (score -1):

If you read the rest of the error message it will point out that create view has to be the first statement or something along those lines.

Try:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[testView]'))
    DROP VIEW [dbo].[testView]
GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[testView]
AS
```

Comment: There is no 'rest of the error message', unless it's hidden in a white font.

Comment: :S 
My bad. I was bumping my head against something a while ago where it kept giving me the following error:
'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.
I thought you were having a similar problem.